# RabbitMQ multi server instances - only one active consumer

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have node.js server, which is also a rabbitmq consumer.
I want to scale my app to multiple instances, but keep only consumer active.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: multi instances of what? RabbitMQ or Node.js?

Comment: of node.js, and to keep only one consumer active

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to state that you want exclusive access to the queue when you start consuming.
Information available [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume.exclusive)
This means that the first consumer will get exclusive access, any other attempt after that will get rejected.

Extract of relevant information from provided link below:

> consume(short reserved-1, queue-name queue, consumer-tag consumer-tag,
>   no-local no-local, no-ack no-ack, bit exclusive, no-wait no-wait,
>   table arguments) ➔ consume-ok

and the exclusive bit information

> bit exclusive
>
> Request exclusive consumer access, meaning only this consumer can
>   access the queue.
>
> The client MAY NOT gain exclusive access to a queue that already has
>   active consumers. Error code: access-refused